# In selenium how to avoid TimeoutException error after multiple hits in sequence?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

With Python3 and selenium I want to automate the search on a public information site. In this site it is necessary to enter the name of a person, then select the spelling chosen for that name (without or with accents or name variations), access a page with the list of lawsuits found and in this list you can access the page of each case.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import re
```

Name that will be searched

```
name = 'JOSE ROBERTO ARRUDA'
```

Create path, search start link, and empty list to store information

```
firefoxPath="/home/abraji/Documentos/Code/geckodriver"
link = 'https://ww2.stj.jus.br/processo/pesquisa/?aplicacao=processos.ea'
processos = []
```

Call driver and go to first search page

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=firefoxPath)
driver.get(link)
```

Position cursor, fill and click

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#idParteNome'))).click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idParteNome"]').send_keys(name)
time.sleep(6)
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#idBotaoPesquisarFormularioExtendido'))).click()
```

Mark all spelling possibilities for searching

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#idBotaoMarcarTodos'))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#idBotaoPesquisarMarcados'))).click()
time.sleep(1)
```

Check how many pages of data there are - to be used in "for range"

```
capta = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idDivBlocoPaginacaoTopo"]/div/span/span[2]').text
print(capta)
paginas = int(re.search(r'\d+', capta).group(0))
paginas = int(paginas) + 1
print(paginas)
```

Capture routine

```
for acumula in range(1, paginas):

    # Fill the field with the page number and press enter
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idDivBlocoPaginacaoTopo"]/div/span/span[2]/input').send_keys(acumula)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idDivBlocoPaginacaoTopo"]/div/span/span[2]/input').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    time.sleep(2)

    # Captures the number of processes found on the current page - qt
    qt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idDivBlocoMensagem"]/div/b').text
    qt = int(qt) + 2
    print(qt)

    # Iterate from found number of processes
    for item in range(2, qt):

        # Find the XPATH of each process link - start at number 2
        vez = '//*[@id="idBlocoInternoLinhasProcesso"]/div[' + str(item) + ']/span[1]/span[1]/span[1]/span[2]/a'

        # Access the direct link and click
        time.sleep(2)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, vez))).click()
        time.sleep(1)

        # Run tests to get data
        try:
            num_unico = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idProcessoDetalhesBloco1"]/div[6]/span[2]/a').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            num_unico = "sem_numero_unico"

        try:
            nome_proc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idSpanClasseDescricao"]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            nome_proc = "sem_nome_encontrado"

        try:
            data_autu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idProcessoDetalhesBloco1"]/div[5]/span[2]').text
        except NoSuchElementException:
            data_autu = "sem_data_encontrada"

        # Fills dictionary and list
        dicionario = {"num_unico": num_unico,
                      "nome_proc": nome_proc,
                      "data_autu": data_autu
                                 }
        processos.append(dicionario)

        # Return a page to click on next process
        driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")

# Close driver
driver.quit()
```

After about 30 hits to the direct links with the information of each process I have this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a901a514bd82> in <module>
     16 
     17         time.sleep(2)
---> 18         WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, vez))).click()
     19         time.sleep(1)
     20 

~/Documentos/Code/publique_se/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```

Apparently the site gets slow and the script shows error because it can't find the information, right?

Please, on sites where selenium traverses multiple pages is there a way to avoid this kind of error?

Can the website itself slow down when it perceives hits in sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using threads to wait which is not a good way and causing errors as you are getting

you are using  `time.sleep(2)` instead use explicit waits of selenium

Example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath")))

element.click();
```

Note: You need to change the time from `20` to as per your application approx time you observe

Comment: Thanks a lot @ShubhamJain, now it works. Please, I just now have a hard time figuring out the correct number of items per page, to call the direct link of each process.

Comment: I'm using (qt = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="idDivBlocoMensagem"]/div/b').text) to figure out the total number of processes, and I make a for to change each link. But the problem is that this website only shows 41 links per page, starting with 2

Comment: So you would need to know how many link lines there are on each page. (example of xpath //*[@id="idBlocoInternoLinhasProcesso"]/div[41]/span[1]/span[1]/span[1]/span[2]/a)

Comment: Please would you have an idea? Or I better post a new question?

Comment: Yes please post an another question and kindly accept the answer as it works for it